# How to replace characters in a string array within a for loop?

Tags: java, arrays, string, encryption

My method is supposed to get text from a jTextArea called enc and split it (at every ",") in a String array with variable name b. Then its supposed to put it in a for loop and replace each letter with a character in my String[] chars array but its not working. Help would be appreciated.

My code:

```
String[] chars = {"!", "£", "$", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "<", ">", "/", "\\", "#", "?", "[", "]", "{", "}", "-", "+", "=", "n", "@", "t", "|", "a", "."};
String[] encrypted;
public void replace(){
    String a = enc.getText();
    String[] b = a.split(",");
    int length = a.length();
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){


        encrypted[i] = b[i].replace(b[i], chars[i]);


    }
    enc.append("\n" + encrypted.toString());

}
```

Comment: Isn't `b[i].replace(b[i], chars[i])` equivalent to `chars[i]`?

Comment: I don't see where `encrypted` is initialized

Comment: its not clear what you're trying to achieve here, can you put an example for the string 'a' and the expected output

Comment: It is not working. Great error description, please give a stack trace or compiler error. `NullPointerException`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this `enc.append("\n" + encrypted.toString());`

use like this. `enc.append("\n" + Arrays.toString(encrypted));`

Comment: Thanks, it helped! Still had some minor issues but i fixed them.

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems with your code:

1. You are not initializing `encrypted`.
2. You want to replace the whole plain string with the chars, but what if the plain string is longer than the `chars` array? You will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

It isn't clear what you are trying to accomplish with this code. You need to think of a better algorithm for encrypting string than just replacing char by char. This will generate the same encrypted strings. Consider offset cipher ([Caesar Cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher)). It is very simple and easy to implement.